# git packs: creation selective "protected" and optimised pack?

Tags: git

$dayjob's main repository is pretty big, and has both relatively stable "update-only" branches and fairly aggressively updated and rewritten development and integration branches.

`git gc --aggressive` (or an even more aggressive strategy via `--repack`) work well and can significantly improve the size of the repository, however they repack the entire repository meaning they pack a bunch of soon-to-be garbage from dev branches alongside the stable ones.

Is there an easy way to give git a list of "stable" branches it *should* pack together, and possibly only incrementally update unless the pack is explicitly marked for replacement or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's standard GC behavior doesn't have any options to control what gets packed together like that.  It will by default pack unpacked objects into a pack, and repack objects into a large pack if there are too many packs (by default, 50).

If you want to create a specific pack that's optimized and that you want to keep no matter what, you can do something like this:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
# Adjust to print whatever refs you want.
echo refs/heads/master | git pack-objects --revs --progress $tmpdir/pack
touch "$tmpdir/$(basename "$tmpdir/"*.pack .pack).keep"
mv "$tmpdir/"* .git/objects/pack/
rm -fr "$tmpdir"
```

That will pack all of the refs (in my example, `master`) into one pack and mark it to be kept with a `.keep` file.  Other objects will still be packed if there are enough loose objects.

When you want to repack the repository, delete the existing `.keep` file, and run those commands again.

If you want a more aggressive packing, you can pass additional arguments to `git pack-objects` that will produce such a packing.

If you use a standard hosting solution, then the server side should take care of automatically packing on the server at a reasonable interval.